# Spark - How to identify a failed Job through 'SparkLauncher'

Tags: apache-spark

I am using Spark 2.0 and sometimes my job fails due to problems with input. For example, I am reading CSV files off from a S3 folder based on the date, and if there's no data for the current date, my job has nothing to process so it throws an exception as follows. This gets printed in the driver's logs.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: s3n://data/2016-08-31/*.csv;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.failAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.failAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:67)
...
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:729)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
 16/09/03 10:51:54 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
 16/09/03 10:51:54 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.1.33:4040
 16/09/03 10:51:54 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
 16/09/03 10:51:54 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down
Spark App app-20160903105040-0007 state changed to FINISHED
```

However, despite this uncaught exception, my Spark Job status is 'FINISHED'. I would expect it to be in 'FAILED' status because there was an exception. Why is it marked as FINISHED? How can I find out whether the job failed or not?

Note: I am spawning the Spark jobs using SparkLauncher, and listening to state changes through AppHandle. But the state change I receive is FINISHED whereas I am expecting FAILED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one **FINISHED** you see is for Spark application not a job. It is **FINISHED** since the Spark context was able to start and stop properly.

You can see any job information using **JavaSparkStatusTracker**.
For active jobs nothing additional should be done, since it has ".getActiveJobIds" method.

For getting finished/failed you will need to setup the job group ID in the thread from which you are calling for a spark execution:

```
JavaSparkContext sc;
... 
sc.setJobGroup(MY_JOB_ID, "Some description");
```

Then whenever you need, you can read the status of each job with in specified job group:

```
JavaSparkStatusTracker statusTracker = sc.statusTracker();
for (int jobId : statusTracker.getJobIdsForGroup(JOB_GROUP_ALL)) {
    final SparkJobInfo jobInfo = statusTracker.getJobInfo(jobId);
    final JobExecutionStatus status = jobInfo.status();
}
```

The JobExecutionStatus can be one of **RUNNING**, **SUCCEEDED**, **FAILED**, **UNKNOWN**; The last one is for case of job is submitted, but not actually started.

**Note:** all this is available from Spark driver, which is jar you are launching using **SparkLauncher**. So above code should be placed into the jar.

If you want to check in general is there any failures from the side of **Spark Launcher**, you can exit the application started by Jar with exit code different than 0 using kind of **System.exit(1)**, if detected a job failure. The **Process** returned by **SparkLauncher::launch** contains **exitValue** method, so you can detect is it failed or no.

Answer (score -1):

> you can always go to spark history server and click on your job id to
>   get the job details.

[image: spark job history server job lists]

> If you are using yarn then you can go to resource manager web UI to
>   track your job status.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kamal. However, I am looking for a way to programmatically do this. On a separate note, even the Spark Master's Web UI shows the job as 'FINISHED' where as I would expect it to be 'FAILED'.

Comment: You can click on the job to see the details. Also if the job fails it will show under the failed job section in yarn UI.